# Get current request's credentials for using in WebRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When accessing my site, the user has to enter his credentials. They are basically plain directory access credentials.
At a certain point I check if a certain file they want to download exists by calling

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(checkUri.AbsoluteUri);
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Although I can access the checkUri from the browser, I get a 401 when doing the above check. I think I have to set the

```
req.Credentials
```

But I don't know where the current credentials are stored...

Any ideas?

**--Update--**

- Integrated Windows Authentication: No
- Allow Anonymous: Off
- Caler: Link on page of same site (GET)
- Impersonation: default is off (don't even know how to enable it in asp.net mvc)

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar problem on a site where I'm using forms authentication, I was able to solve this problem by using the code provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3139016/Forms-Authentication-and-using-Current-User-Creden.aspx#3139377) as the second reply in the thread.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
// Add the current authentication cookie to the request
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
Cookie authenticationCookie = new Cookie(
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
    cookie.Value,
    cookie.Path,
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);

req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie);

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want this:

```
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: Well, I tried both DefaultCredentials and DefaultNetworkCredentials.
Both nuthin'

Comment: Is your site running with Integrated Windows Authentication turned on and Allow Anonymous off?  What is making the call?  If your caller is itself a website, do you have impersonation turned on and Kerberos delegation properly configured?

Comment: Thx for the comment. Not sure about impersonation and kerberos delegation. How do I check?
Put what I know in OP.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to enable Integrated Windows Authentication.

I don't know what happens in ASP.NET MVC, but in ASP.NET Web Forms impersonation is turned on by:

```
<identity impersonate="true">
```

in web.config.