# C# - passing authentication credentials with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, authentication, cookies, httpwebrequest

I am working on a tool that parses html source of given urls. Some of them are password protected.

Here is my question: How can I pass authentication credentials with the HttpWebRequest? Does it require setting up a cookie?
These are new grounds to me, thus examples would be very helpful.

In summary, I use the following for requests that not require an authentication.

```
...
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(<URL   STRING>));
...
HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Depends entirely on how the site that you're requesting from handles authentication. Can you fill in any details? (For most internet sites, you'll have to present a session cookie obtained from a logged in user.)

Comment: There is login, password and employee ID required while accessing authenticated pages in a normal way.

Answer (score 5):

For Basic authentication (not sure about other authentication schemes):

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: The same works well for `Integrated Windows` authentication scheme as well if you have domain credentials of a specific user.

Answer (score 1):

For forms authentication where a valid cookie is available in the page Context, you can use this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589723/253131